# How to get meaningful information out of SendAsync exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception, httpclient

I've written some code which does a post to a remote webservice. I've tried using both HttpClient.PostAync as well as HttpClient.SendAsync, where with the former I just provide everything up front, and with the later I build an HttpRequestMessage with the appropriate values. In my testing today I'm getting some type of exception here. The same exception with both implementations. Presumably a timeout, or other error on the remote side / transmission. When I get this exception, it comes with the generic message of 'A task was cancelled'.

The code looks something like this:

```
            using (MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                //formData.Add(clientIDContent, "client_id");
                //formData.Add(clientSecretContent, "client_secret");
                formData.Add(quoteIDContent, "CPQuoteID");
                formData.Add(poNumContent, "PONumber");
                formData.Add(dealerNumContent, "DealerNumber");
                formData.Add(orderUserContent, "OrderingUser");
                formData.Add(fileContent, "order-file");

                try
                {
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(actionURL, formData);
                    int I = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                }

            }
```

the exception I get back is of type TaskCanceledException. The inner exception also carries no meaningful information. There must be a way to get better information back from this. It's frustrating to debug issues when our logs contain only generic messages like this. How do I get this info?

Just a bit more info. I'm operating under the assumption here that the HTTP client does this operation with a Task. At some point the task times out. I don't know if this is because the HTTP timeout is greater than the task timeout in some way, or if the HttpClient object catches the timeout exception, consumes it, then cancels the task throwing the cancellation exception. Either way, it would seem that meaningful information about the underlying issue is lost. Info I'd like to log.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the cause is a timeout, because the task is indeed cancelled after the timeout is reached. HTTP errors returned from the remote server do not throw but manifest as failed status codes, while general connectivity errors (including timeout) do throw.

Comment: @TimMedora Agreed, this is the behavior I'm seeing as well. What I don't understand is that what happens first? Like is there a way to set the task cancellation time way beyond the HTTP timeout such that the underlying timeout exception is returned here? Anything more meaningful that 'A task was canceled' would be super helpful in our logs lol.

Comment: It's confusing, especially since the comments for `SendAsync()` say that `HttpRequestException` will be thrown when "The request failed due to an underlying issue such as network connectivity, DNS failure, server certificate validation or timeout." But regardless of the exception type, what additional information would you obtain about a timeout? The only thing I can think of is knowing if the timeout occurred during connection or during execution of the request.

Comment: @TimMedora Well the issue with assuming that 'A task was canceled' means timeout is that I can genuinely cancel the task. Now there's ambiguity. Was the task canceled on purpose, or did something else happen to cause the issue... like a timeout. I was just hoping there may be something somewhere that I haven't found that indicates WHY the task was canceled, or similar.  Also, yes the MSDN doc wasn't helpful in that it misleads you into thinking you'll get one exception back but you actually get another.

Comment: Yes, I can see the ambiguity there. Looking through the source code for `HttpClient`, it doesn't seem there's a lot of flexibility in this area. You could probably disambiguate by setting an infinite timeout and then issuing your own cancellation after n seconds. That way, you could determine if the cancellation came because of timeout or because of something further up the call stack. There's also the case where the remote server issues its own timeout and breaks the connection. I imagine that would manifest differently than task cancellation.

Comment: @TimMedora That's not a half bad idea Tim. Thanks for the input. I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you run through Visual Studio debug? Then try getting the full call stack, might be helpful. Also if you control the server, you should see the error in the server log, if indeed it's caused by the server.

Comment: @PoulBak I do, I had not inspected the call stack. Only the exception and inner exceptions down the tree. Maybe something is buried down in there.